# How to make uitableview to fill all my view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am very new to iOS. Can anyone tell me how to fix this, to fill all my view with `UITableView`:

[image: Check Image]

I am trying to do it with auto layout and constraints but I don't know why isn't working.

Comment: Did you apply the red color to the table view's cells or the table view itself? It could also be the case that your table view **is** full height it's content (the cells) aren't. -- You can figure that out by giving the table view a different background color than the cells.

Comment: @fluidsonic i added red color to Cells, now i added black color to the tableView, and now the background of tableView is all black, so that means it is fully height and the cells aren't, right ?

Comment: So the table view **is full height** as you wanted it to. How else do you want it to look like?

Comment: @fluidsonic yeah you're right, i did a mistake, cuz i want to fill the view with these 5 cells, cuz when i run in iPhone5 looks good, but when i run in iPhone6 it's looking like in a photo i posted.

Comment: @LabinotBajrami. It's solved? Right. More: please try 100 cells first. :)

Comment: @anhtu Yes it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to have the cells at equal height so that all cells together fit exactly the height of the screen.

You cannot do that with auto layout. You have to tell the table view the height you'd like the rows to have like so:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let heightOfVisibleTableViewArea = view.bounds.height - topLayoutGuide.length - bottomLayoutGuide.length
    let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)

    tableView.rowHeight = heightOfVisibleTableViewArea / CGFloat(numberOfRows)
}
```

Note that this code assumes that you **don't** implement the method `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`.

Comment: Thanks for this!  In my case, I noticed that setting the "rowHeight" seems to trigger viewWillLayoutSubviews() to be called indefinitely.  I had to add a check to only set "rowHeight" once.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To fill the whole view, with a table view, I use four constraints:

One. tableView centre = view centre. 
Two. tableView width = view width.
Three. tableView vertical distance to top layout guide = 0
Four. tableView vertical distance to bottom layout guide = 0.

To fill everything with the same color, I set the backgroundColor of the tableView, then set the backgroundColor of the cells to [UIColor clearColor].

Comment: I would use trailing and leading spaces constraints instead of centering and giving width to view.